# Can't seem to figure out how to get .toggle function working in jQuery, the library is included, I have a jsFiddle for testing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can't seem to figure out why none of my console logs or alerts are working in this jQuery toggle function. I haven't used jQuery in a while so am not sure If I am doing something wrong or if there is a configuration issue with the script include.

Here is the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/anders_kitson/8ar9mvp4/1/

Here is the code

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }],

    navigation: {
        buttonOptions: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
});

const b = document.createElement('button');
b.textContent = ' ';
b.style.position = 'absolute';
b.style.right = "0px" 
b.style.top = '10px';
b.className = "toggleMe"
b.setAttribute("id", "buttonToggle");

$( "#buttonToggle" ).toggle(function() {
  alert( "First handler for .toggle() called." );
  console.log("test")
}, function() {
  alert( "Second handler for .toggle() called." );
  console.log("test1")
});

/* b.addEventListener('click', function () {
    chart.fullscreen.toggle();
    //b.classList.remove("toggleMe");
    //b.className = "toggleMeOff"
}); */

chart.container.appendChild(b);
```

Comment: [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will help

Comment: you linked to the wrong toggle, I am using the toggle event https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ which I copied and pasted from the jquery docs

Comment: On that page you linked to, in the upper right: version deprecated: 1.8, removed: 1.9.

Comment: You're using jQuery 3.6, the documentation for the method you linked says it was deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: ahh makes sense, will have to see what version were running on the site then, to see if I can use this or not, probably not. Is there any such function in the new api

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which function you would like to expect with the toggle.

 This code gives you the second handler alert.

```js
$( "#container" ).after('<button id="buttonToggle">Click Me!</button>');

$( "#buttonToggle" ).toggle(function() {
  alert( "First handler for .toggle() called." );
  console.log("test")
}, function() {
  alert( "Second handler for .toggle() called." );
  console.log("test1")
});
```